# Couture death information from SoftKinetic DS311 using openCV?

Tags: opencv

I wonder if there is a possibility to get a depth information from SoftKinetic DS311 using only opencv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible. You need to setup a callback using the SoftKinetic SDK to be notified of new depth frames, and that convert that to `cv::Mat`.

You might be interested on [this project](https://github.com/ph4m/DepthSenseGrabber) since it shows how to do exactly that.